# Reading an input file line

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and also tied to an old version 2.5.2 at my work.  I'm simply trying to print the information at particular line number of an input file (sys.argv[1] which is the input file "numbers.txt").  It don't think it should be that hard, obviously, but I've been trying all after noon and keep getting errors for everything I have tried.  The following just prints the value of nr, not the contents of the line given by nr.

```
import sys, os
sys.argv[1]
numbers = sys.argv[1]
f = open(numbers,'r')
for nr, line in enumerate(f):
    if line[:8]=="03 00 01":
        print nr
```

I would like to print the contents at line nr that satisfies the test condition.  I would also please like to know how to print the contents of the line given by nr+1 or nr-1.  The ideas I have found usually give errors such as "mixing a iteration and read methods would lose data" or "bla bla bla not defined such as next()".  I'm sorry if this is novice nuisance type question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
print nr
```

just print the line

```
print line
```

And while enumerating you cannot access the next element until we reach there, but you can access the previous element by storing the current element in a temporary variable at the end of the iteration.

Comment: thefortheye, thanks, this now seems so obvious.  I need to test for particular strings at the start of consecutive lines, so your simple suggestion should get me further on down the road. Thanks again.

Comment: thefortheye, I finally got my problem solved with your lead.  This is huge, it may literally make the difference in keeping my job.